# How to cap a value between 2 integers?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I am trying to state a range between two integers, i.e. 0 and 3. Anything that is lower than this range will loop back from the upper end, and vice versa. It is kind of like how integers work in other languages.

For example (range 0 to 3):

```
cap(-4) // returns 0
cap(-3) // returns 1
cap(-2) // returns 2
cap(-1) // returns 3
cap(0)  // returns 0
cap(1)  // returns 1
cap(2)  // returns 2
cap(3)  // returns 3
cap(4)  // returns 0
cap(5)  // returns 1
cap(6)  // returns 2
cap(7)  // returns 3
cap(8)  // returns 0
```

The best working code that I could make is this:

```
const cap = (value, low, high) =>  value < low ? high - (high - value) % (high - low + 1) : (value - low) % (high - low + 1) + low
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I feel like there's a way to do this without using conditional.

Comment: Could the `low` or `high` go into the negatives?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Not that I anticipate. The resulting function could work with negative numbers regardless, but it isn't how I intend to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the special case of ranges starting from zero:

```
const mod = (n, m) => (m + n % m) % m;
```

Then the overall operation in terms of that:

```
const cap = (value, low, high) => low + mod(value - low, high - low + 1);
```